# Entity Relationship Model / Relational Model and Normalization of Attributes

Tags: attributes, entity, normalization, entity-relationship, relational

I have the following question. If i have a relation such as

Request = {[Request_ID: Int,Status: String,Start_Time: Date]}

Request_ID is the primary attribute and Status and Start_Time are normal attributes.

If I would like to normalize the Status from String to Int for example my ref_Status table would look something like this.

Status_ID | Status Name

1         | New

2 | Old

3 | finished

Does through this normalization the Attribute Status become an Entity ?

Attributes are used to characterize an Entity which the Status-ID does but at the same time it is a foreign key to a different table even though it only holds the name which would hint me that this would be an Entity.

I would be really glad if someone could help me out with this.

Thank you in Advance and I hope my Question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is introducing a surrogate key for the status.  It has nothing to do with normalization.

Entities in Chen's ER model are represented by *values*, and a status can be interpreted as an entity regardless of whether it's represented by an int in one table or a string in another.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you also tell me why status is not an attribute but an entity? I thought that status would be a characteristic of the entity request and thats why i thought it would be an attribute. The relationship with Request would be One Request has one Status. To me this seems similar to one person has one name - which is commonly designed as an attribute

Comment: I think i just answered my own question - Attributes don't change over time which is the case for Status. So Status is more likely to be an entity.

Thank you :) !

Comment: An entity can be the value of an attribute of another entity.  They're not mutually exclusive.